# Many questions training unbalanced and duplicated data

Tags: classification, training, class-imbalance, transformer

I'm a DS student. I have like 30.000 of bank statements, all labeled with a specific category(cat1, cat2, ...). With that data I'm trying to train a classification model but I found several problems:

- The category that has more statements has 10k, the one with less 100 (unbalanced dataset)
- Many rows are repeated with the same text ( for example "Buy for a total of X$ in the supermarket Y", but the repeated rows appears in each label)

- Should I train with repeated statements? if I do so the model will be trained for some specific cases and the predicted results will not be real because for example if I have repeated statements with the same label:

A, B, B, B, B, B (labels)

and I take only one row with label A and B, since the statement will be repeated the accuracy predicting the others B's will be 100%.

- If I do not train with repeated statements am I not deleting important information about my data and can affect the prediction later?
- Should I undersampling or oversampling? It's correct for this kind of data? I will have more repeated rows in the case of oversampling, and undersampling I'll lose a lot of information.

I do not know if what I'm thinking has some sense. I really need some tips in order to train my data.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated entry is as good as you are adding weighted samples *i.e. those samples will have extra weights in the learning processes.*

 So, you should look into the data and decide if that weight is valid for those samples. *Otherwise, it might overfit the Model*

**On Oversample, Undersample**

 This is a very broad question. Please do read some relevant blogs/SE posts.

 You should also try

*- Both, Over-sampling and Under-sampling together i.e. Hybrid approach

- Adding appropriate class-weight to the learning i.e. Cost-sensitive learning*

You may start here -

*[Python Library](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

[Blog](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/imbalanced-data/)

[Blog](https://www.svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/)

[Book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-98074-4)*